# AWS Dead letter queue redrive block incoming message redrive

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I am trying to use AWS Dead Letter Queues (DLQ) and DLQ Redrive, but I need to be sure that the DLQ Redrive won't also move incoming messages.

For example, I have a Lambda function that always fails, so messages are always sent to the DLQ. If I start a DLQ Redrive, will the messages loop indefinitely until the DLQ stops? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dead-letter queues are used to isolate the problematic messages from the lambda function. This is useful because it ensures that messages are not lost and are instead preserved in the DLQ. Since the messages are preserved, it will enable us to log/alert/investigate/redrive the failed messages.

In your specific case, if the lambda function starts throwing exceptions for all incoming messages, all the messages will be moved to the DLQ. However, if you redrive the messages without fixing the lambda function, then those messages will be once again moved back to the DLQ.

p.s. Ideally, you should fix the problem in the lambda function before attempting to redrive the messages to the source queue.

Comment: The bad lambda function throw errors on purpose, it was specifically to make test on DLQs and the redrive function inside the AWS console.
What I want to know is : if I send the message back to the original queue, they fail again and go in the DLQ, will the redrive policy take those messages and send them backagain, or will they stay here until we start another redrive policy ?

Comment: No, it won't resend the newly received messages to the lambda function during redrive, so there is no possibility of an infinite loop for failed messages in the mentioned scenario.